# Qt hide minimize, maximize and close buttons

Tags: qt, hide, minimize, maximize

Do you know how to hide minimize, maximize and close buttons of title bar in Qt. I especially need to hide it on QMainWindow.

Comment: Could you mention why you need to do that?

Comment: i dont want user close my application by pressing x on the corner. i want him to make some processes before quit operation.

Answer (score 27):

Set this window flags `Qt::Window | Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint`

Note, that on some platforms it behaves in different way. For example on Mac OS X it Disables, (not hides) close/minimize/maximize buttons

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Qt qml then, to remove minimize, maximize and close button, set the frameless window flag in the window function in your main.qml file, like below:

```
flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
```

Answer (score 7):

Just watch how [Window Flags Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html) works!

Comment: thank u mosg. 
actually my main problem is hiding close button on mainWindow.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achived by using an eventFilter on the QEvent::Close event from your MainWindow

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) {

    if (event->type() == QEvent::Close) {
        event->ignore();
        doWhateverYouNeedToDoBeforeClosingTheApplication();
        return true;
    }
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event);
}

void MainWindow::doWhateverYouNeedToDoBeforeClosingTheApplication() {
    // Do here what ever you need to do
    // ...
    // ...

    // and finally quit
    qApp->quit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the close button, you can override the closeEvent() of QmainWindow

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):    
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        event.ignore()
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

flags: `Qt.Dialog | Qt.WindowCancelButtonHint | Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint`

this also works for a window item

flags: `Qt.Window | Qt.WindowTitleHint`

Comment: Based on those names, I wouldn't think those are the correct flags for this...  Is that why the OP was having problems finding it?