# Creating Window That Has No Close Button in Qt

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt-designer

Is there anyway to create window like below image , that has no close button in qt designer ?

[image: sample image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt hide minimize, maximize and close buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211272/qt-hide-minimize-maximize-and-close-buttons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a look like that you'd want to use the `setWindowsFlags` function, and pass in `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint` `Qt::FramelessWindowHint`, in C++ this would look like `someUi->setWindowsFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint)` but I'm not sure for PyQt.

Comment: self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint) in qt