# How to block the 'native close button' of a QProgressDialog on OS X?

Tags: c++, qt, qprogressdialog

I'm creating a `QProgressDialog` as follows:

```
QProgressDialog progressDialog = new QProgressDialog(tr("Calculating..."), NULL, 0, 100, this);
progressDialog->setAutoClose(true);
progressDialog->setValue(0);
progressDialog->setWindowTitle(tr("Calculate Weights"));
progressDialog->setWindowFlags(progressDialog->windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
progressDialog->show();
```

Note that I'm using the `Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint` flag to disable the 'native close button'. It seems to work well on **Windows** but not on **OS X** (on **OS X** the close button is still available and the user can close the `QProgressDialog`).

I have also tested with other flags (e.g. `Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint`, `Qt::WindowTransparentForInput`) but none have solved my problem.

Sure I can use the `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` flag to remove the 'entire border of the window' but it is not my objective, since I just want to disable the close button.

What window flag can I use to disable/block the `QProgressBar` close button on **OS X**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt hide minimize, maximize and close buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211272/qt-hide-minimize-maximize-and-close-buttons)

Answer (score 1):

Subclass the dialog, and re-implement `QCloseEvent`.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcloseevent.html

In that you can stop and ignore, or respond with a "are you sure" kinds of things.

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-application-example.html#close-event-handler

```
// in your MyProgressDialog.h
protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) override;

// In your MyProgressDialog.cpp
void MyProgressDialog::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    //if (maybeSave()) {
    //    writeSettings();
    //    event->accept();
    //} else {
    //    event->ignore();
    //}
    if(event->spontaneous())// this might work, or you can just use an else on the next if statement instead.
        event->ignore();
    else if(m_progress == 100 || m_isDone)
        event->accept();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @phyatt, it seems to be a great solution but I was looking for an easier one, maybe using **window flags**. If it is not possible on **OS X** I will probably follow your tip and create a subclass of `QProgressDialog`.

Comment: A lot of customization can happen using window flags (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html) and widget attributes (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum), but when you start doing some corner case stuff, you have nearly unlimited customization with the standard subclassing route.

Comment: No, I haven't found this question before. It worked very well, thank you so much @phyatt.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @phyatt it was solved by using the following combination of flags:

```
progressDialog->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
```

As answered here: [Qt hide minimize, maximize and close buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211272/qt-hide-minimize-maximize-and-close-buttons/3216265#3216265)